# JQ - get keys without values in a simple list

Tags: json, shell, unix, jq

I have a Pipfile.lock JSON file that I need to parse with the `jq` tool. The structure of the file is:

```
{
     //...
     "default": {
           "value1": {
           // lots of nested properties with values
           },
           "value2": {
           //similar stuff as for value1
           }
           //... 
     }
}
```

What do now is `jq '.default | keys' Pipfile.lock` which produces:

```
[
    "value1",
    "value2",
...
]
```

I would need the output to:

1. Not produce the first line with `[` and last line with `]`
2. Have the values printed without quotes

Is this feasible just using `jq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the elements of the array, not the array itself.

```
jq '.default | keys[]' Pipfile.lock
```

Use the `-r` option to output raw strings, rather than JSON strings.

```
jq -r '.default | keys[]' Pipfile.lock
```